# Why don't my rc files load when nesting ssh calls?

Tags: ssh

When I run

```sh
ssh user1@server1 'ssh user2@server2'
```

I am able to log in, but my rc files don't load. Even when I `source .zshrc` I still have a blank prompt and no color. I even tried `exec zsh` and `exec bash` as a fallback but nothing changed. What's going on here and how can I fix it?

Comment: `.bashrc` and `.zshrc` are only loaded for interactive shells -- ones where `[[ $- = *i* ]]`.

Comment: Don't nest calls that way anyhow; OpenSSH has a built-in proxy command that does it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Avoiding The Problem

Don't do that in the first place. Instead, use ssh's built-in `ProxyJump` support:

```
ssh -o 'ProxyJump user1@server1' user2@server2
```

You can even make this automatic for all connections to `server2`, by putting something like the following in your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host server2
    ProxyJump user1@server1
```

---

#### Explaining The Problem

There are a few behaviors at play:

- When `ssh` is passed a command, it doesn't create a TTY by default (unless passed `-t` or `-tt`). This impacts any invoked program's ability to manipulate terminal settings; `isatty(0)` is also a conventional way to do a "am-I-interactive?" check. If a shell's stdin isn't attached to a TTY, this is one way it can decide that it isn't interactive.
- When a shell is started with `"$SHELL" -c "command"` -- as `ssh` does when passed a command to run -- it doesn't run in interactive mode, and so doesn't force `rc` files (which are explicitly for interactive use).

Comment: This didn't work for me. When I enter that command my shell just hangs. Also when I run `ProxyJump` directly on either my home machine or `server1` it says "command not found" - is this an actual command or is it built into ssh somehow?

Comment: ProxyJump is an option to ssh; it has to be right after the `-o` flag, as I showed it. It's documented in `man ssh`.

Comment: If you want to figure out what's going on when ssh appears to be hanging, that's what `-v` is for.

Comment: Is it supposed to be inside the quotes, not outside them?

Comment: Yes, it has to be in quotes, so the entire option (both the name and value) are passed in a single string.

Comment: If you're still having problems, show me the actual command line exactly as you're running it, and the logs emitted when adding `-v` as the first option (before the `-o`).

Comment: You maybe be able to abbreviate the `ProxyJump` option using `-J`: `ssh -J user2@server2 user1@server1`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I swear there's like a chat feature on here but I can't remember how to get to it

Comment: @MichaelDorst see https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95800/room-for-charles-duffy-and-michael-dorst